# Use NHibernate generated sqls to sync with read-only database

Tags: c#, nhibernate, database-replication

I'm trying to leverage a sync mechanism inside my application, I need to provide read-only database throughout my application since my data is not frequently updated (for performance and scalability optimization reasons). I thought I could do this by executing sql inserts and updates generated by NH on the source publisher database to the read-only one (subscriber).

My application is database agnostic, so I wouldn't focus on replication features of each RDBMS.

The question is: Is this a reliable approach, and what's the best lock mechanisms to use in this situation?

Comment: this sonds like CQRS (http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html)